# Dont work autoplay in carousel with additional images

Tags: php, owl-carousel, opencart2.3

Have a images and additional images in opencart 2.3.0.2
I rechange carousel for images and want to make own picture and additional together, and make this

```
<?php if ($thumb || $images) { ?>
<div class="thumbnails">
    <div class="image">
        <?php if ($thumb) { ?>
            <div class="item">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="<?php echo $popup; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" /></a>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>


        <?php if ($images) { ?>

            <?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
                <div class="item">

                    <a class="thumbnail" href="<?php echo $image['popup']; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>"> <img src="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" /></a>
                </div>

            <?php } ?>

        <?php } ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

and this

```
$('.image').owlCarousel({

    items: 1,       
    navigation: true,
    pagination: true,
    autoplay: 1000,
    itemsDesktop : [1199,1],
    itemsDesktopSmall : [991,1],
    itemsTablet : [650,1],
    itemsMobile : [479,1]


});
```

all puctures of product stay together in carousel, but i want make autostart, and his dont work. What here wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Your may try this.

```
autoplay:true, 
autoplayTimeout:1000,
```

Add These two lines. instead of `autoplay: 1000,`

```
$('.image').owlCarousel({
    items: 1,       
    navigation: true,
    pagination: true,
    autoplay:true,  //Add This Line
    autoplayTimeout:1000, //Add This Line
    //autoplay: 1000, //Remove This Line
    itemsDesktop : [1199,1],
    itemsDesktopSmall : [991,1],
    itemsTablet : [650,1],
    itemsMobile : [479,1]
});
```

Comment: no, any error, navigation have, paginatin have, but auto play dont work